# How do I remove the chrx partition on a chromebook running crouton?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, chrome-book

I hope this is the right place for this. If not, let me know where would be more appropriate. I have chosen to ask it here because I am assuming/hoping that the flexibility of linux will allow me to remove/modify the partition while within Ubuntu.

I recently bought a chromebook (Haier 11 G2), and wanted to load linux. So I tried to use chrx, and I "sucessfully" created a partition to load GalliumOS. However, I then realized that there is currently not the right firmware mod out there to make this possible on my hardware. So I decided to go with crouton while I wait. (I got a very new model, perhaps a mistake).

Crouton created a 1.6GB partition, which is enough for the OS (trusty), desktop (xcfe), Chromium, and 18MB free space. I also have a drive visible in the linux file system called "9.7GB Volume". I am fairly certain this is the partition I made for GalliumOS. It even has some of the GalliumOS packages in it.

My question is: How do I remove this partition, to free up that space for crouton?

I have already tried powerwashing my chromebook, and that has not worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, doing a full recovery is the only way to re-partition your Chromebook back to the OEM sizes and structure and regain the space that was allotted to Gallium OS. The best tool for that is the [Chromebook Recovery Utility](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromebook-recovery-utili/jndclpdbaamdhonoechobihbbiimdgai?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

A `powerwash` removes all user data including wiping out any crouton chroots so you do get some space back but it doesn't re-partition your Chromebook like a full recovery.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem as you; I have a Dell Chromebook 13 which I installed Gallium OS on a little while ago. Then I only had 8 GB on Chrome OS.


I attempted to do what user76417 explained above; however, in order to use the Chromebook Recovery Utility, you must have a consistent WiFi connection, which I do not have. Here is another possible solution, one which allows you to manually set how much storage you want without any WiFi:

1. Get into crosh(**ctrl - alt - t**), then into your shell by typing **shell**
2. Type **sudo fdisk -l** - this lists your different partitions. Find the partition which you set aside for Gallium; it will be labeled as "ChromeOS root fs". Make sure the size matches up to the amount you gave Gallium!
3. Type **sudo fdisk /(wherever your partitions are stored)** - my partitions were in /dev/sda/, though I believe this changes according to the different type of Chromebook you use.
4. Type **d**. The system will ask you which partition you want to delete. Usually, Gallium is installed on partition 7, but that could also vary on different Chromebooks.
5. Type **d** again. This time, delete where all of your files are. This is labeled as Microsoft basic data, and the file size will match up to the amount Chrome OS says you have (in the Files app).
6. Type **n**. This time, you're going to recreate the Files partition you deleted. Unless you have a preference as to which sectors the Files app should take up, I just used the default sectors.
7. Type **t**. This time, you need to rename the Files partition to what it was before because it automatically is named Linux Partition. Type "L" to list all the different types of partitions, and type in the number next to Microsoft basic data.
8. Finally, type **w**, and reboot the system. This officially commits all of your changes.

Chrome OS, at least for me, got angry that I tried to change the partitions, and told me that it was "fixing the system" for some time. However, afterwards, it worked, and I was able to restore all of my data without doing a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to install **Linux** on your **Chromebook**, I suggest you look at this blog:

[mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript)

Then, in **developer mode**, open a **shell**:
CTRL+ALT+T and type shell

Download and execute the script to update your **firmware**:

```
cd; curl -LO https://mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh && sudo bash firmware-util.sh
```

Once this step is finished, download the **image** (ISO) of the Linux OS you want to install on your Chromebook. I would take **Gallium OS** as it was specially designed for **Chromebooks**.

Then, using etcher or Rufus, burn it on a USB stick / sdcard.

Finally, you can reboot with the USB / sdcard plugged and press CTRL-L. That will make you switch to gallium OS.
If you want to boot on Chrome OS, just use CTRL-D on startup.

If you want to remove gallium OS, just use a recovery thumb drive and reset your Chromebook.

Comment: More info on the subject: [https://www.linux.com/LEARN/GALLIUMOS-IDEAL-LINUX-DISTRIBUTION-CHROMEBOOK-HARDWARE](https://www.linux.com/LEARN/GALLIUMOS-IDEAL-LINUX-DISTRIBUTION-CHROMEBOOK-HARDWARE)